# Obtaining filesize of all images using ajax and maintaining additional image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The goal - To loop through all images on a page and gather a range of information including image name, original width/height, actual width/height, ratio, display property and FILESIZE.

This is where I am coming unstuck. I am looping through all the images, getting all this information (see below). To obtain the filesize, I am running an ajax call using each image url to return the filesize.

My issue comes that I am unable to return each filesize for each image into a variable (like the other variables) to then be able to display in a list on the page. I have successfully got the filesizes (by console logging) but not using them in any other way.

Here is where I have got to:

```
/*LOOP THROUGH EMAIL IMAGES*/
$('body').find('img').each(function() {

    elem = $(this);
    /*ACTUAL DIMENSIONS*/
    img = new Image();
    img.src = elem.attr('src');
    actWidth = img.width;
    actHeight = img.height;
    /*HTML DIMENSIONS*/
    iWidth = elem.width();
    iHeight = elem.innerHeight();
    /*IMAGE FILENAME*/
    index = img.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    filename = img.src.substr(index);
    /*IMAGE RATIO*/
    ratio = (actWidth / actHeight).toFixed(2);
    newRatio = parseFloat(ratio);

    /*FILESIZE*/
    sizeKB = '';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: img.src,
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){

            //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO COLLECT THE FILESIZE AND PLACE IT IN A VARIABLE THAT CAN BE USED

            console.log(request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));

            sizeKB = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
            return sizeKB;
        }
    });

    console.log(
        'Display: '+displayProp+
        ', Name: '+filename+
        ', Actual size: '+actWidth+'x'+actHeight+
        ', Email size:'+iWidth+'x'+iHeight+
        ', Aspect Ratio: '+newRatio+':1'+
        ', Size: '+sizeKB
    );

});
```

As is stands, when I try to return the sizeKB from the success call back into the console.log with the other data, it is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You ve to wait for the ajax call to complete before you console.log

Comment: Also you ve are re declaring sizeKb variable in success function.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to remove var declaration. I did have a function run from inside the success callback but this will only have the information for the filesize and not all the other information. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you should change your approach of storing info. Use arrays to store information.

Comment: @Harry Bomrah would you have a suggestion of how this could be formatted using arrays instead?

Comment: I have posted an answer using an array. I think it ll solve your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The thing here is you are calling the `console.log()` synchronously while AJAX works asynchron. That means when you are logging the values you don't really have the image's size as it loads a couple of milliseconds later.

Just move your `console.log` into your `success` function and it will work as you call it when the AJAX is done rather than calling it as before said synchronously.

Your old code will be changed from:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: img.src,
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){

        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO COLLECT THE FILESIZE AND PLACE IT IN A VARIABLE THAT CAN BE USED

        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));

        var sizeKB = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
        return sizeKB;
    }
});

console.log(
    'Display: '+displayProp+
    ', Name: '+filename+
    ', Actual size: '+actWidth+'x'+actHeight+
    ', Email size:'+iWidth+'x'+iHeight+
    ', Aspect Ratio: '+newRatio+':1'+
    ', Size: '+sizeKB
);
```

to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: img.src,
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){

        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO COLLECT THE FILESIZE AND PLACE IT IN A VARIABLE THAT CAN BE USED

        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));

        var sizeKB = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');

        console.log(
            'Display: '+displayProp+
            ', Name: '+filename+
            ', Actual size: '+actWidth+'x'+actHeight+
            ', Email size:'+iWidth+'x'+iHeight+
            ', Aspect Ratio: '+newRatio+':1'+
            ', Size: '+sizeKB
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Tarekis. Unfortunately I tried this and the result I get just grabs the last image of the array over and over with the filesizes being the only thing that changes.

Comment: Hmm okay, it's a bit hard to debug this without an physical code fiddle enviorment. But i'll guess this happens because your variables are global and not local, use `var variable` instead of `variable`, this might fix the issue. Also you can try making all your variables an object and sending this object with your success function. So you have `success: function(data, textStatus, request,object){...` and can access `object.filename` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help but think I have managed to find a method (if not bit a ugly). I have added `data: elem, context: this,` to my ajax call and that way I can use the filesize and apply it to the element as a data-attribute. I can then obtain this later on in another function. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Well I did a rough script. This will make an object of all the images and its relevant data. You can use this data later on where ever you want.

```
 var imagesData = {},
    images = $('body').find('img');

images.each(function() {
    var image = {},
        elem = $(this),
        img = new Image();

    img.src = elem.attr('src');
    var index = img.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
        ratio = (img.width / img.height).toFixed(2);

    image["name"] = img.src.substr(index);
    image["width"] = img.width;
    image["height"] = img.height;
    image["html_width"] = elem.width();
    image["html_height"] = elem.innerHeight();
    image["ratio"] = parseFloat(ratio) + ":1";
    imagesData[img.src] = image

    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: img.src,
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
            imagesData[this.url]["size"] = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
        }
    });

});
console.log(imagesData);
```

Comment: Thanks you for this @Harry Bomrah, will be be a big help

Comment: Still a mix of synchron and asynchron, which will render the code useless.

Comment: Well if u make it synchronized then it 'll take too long if there are too many images.. by this method he can start using data instead of waiting for everything to complete.. he can make a synchronized flow with this code too by slightly tweaking it.

Comment: The thing is at `console.log(imagesData);` you already use incomplete Data as `size` is not loaded yet. (It might be, but it is **_very bad_** to assume your service is fast enough! Please do not do this OP!) If your server is slow for any reason, it might take 500ms to get the image's properties and you have no size in your `imagesData` as you synchroniously continue to use something your asynchron called service didn't finish yet!

Comment: As I told he can make it synchronized.